# How to apply dense rank/ partition to animal table? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, left-join, dense-rank

Table:

```
animal height width footlength brand  price age 
------------------------------------------------
cow     3   5   2              fuller   231   8
cow     3   5   2              fuller   242   9 
cow     3   5   2              fuller  1000   2 
chicken 2   2   2              tyson     11   1 
chicken 2   2   2              tyson     11   2 
chicken 2   2   2              tyson     11   3
cow     4    5   2             tyson     90 900
cow     4    5   2             tyson     90 900
```

Okay so in this table I want the groups ranked 1, 2, 3.

Because if animal height width footlength and brand is the same give the rows the same ranking.

The way I have coded it in SQL I keep getting the same rank for each row. vs 3 different ranks.

Any tips on how to better understand dense rank and this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `DENSE_RANK` as follows:

```
SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY height, width, footlength, brand) rnk
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY rnk, animal, height, width, footlength, brand;
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo

Note that we don't need/want a `PARTITION BY` clause with `DENSE_RANK` here, because the rank is to be applied to the entire table.  Using a partition would mean that potentially the same rank values would appear more than once.

Comment: Tim Biegelisen this worked. I don't know why but i kept thinking i needed to use partition by instead of order by in that statement. Thank you. Lots to learn.

Comment: @JessicaWarren Demo link has been added to the answer for your convenience.